# calculate lost hours Schedule vs login time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm wondering if you have a more simplified formula for this.
I'm trying to get lost hours based on the scheduel against the actual login,
however I always can't get to compute 12:00:00

here's the formula I used

```
LOST IN =IF(G52<=$C52,0,IF(G52>$C52,G52-$C52))
LOST OUT = =IF($D52=0,(MOD($D52-G53,1)),IF(G53>=$D52,0,IF(G53<$D52,$D52-G53)))
```

[image: please click here for the table]

please help.

Comment: It is really difficult to know to what the formulas are refering if we do not have the column and row headers shown.

Comment: sorry Scott. I'm not allowed to insert an image yet. I have a link to it though.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iejHX.png

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Craner mentioned, formula references are not visible in your screenshot. However I am just putting in a tentative solution. When you just insert time in Excel say 11:00 AM Excel appends a 0 date to it to make it date/time scale. The 0 date is 1/0/1900, it's actually the 0'th date on date scale, add 1 to it and Excel starts counting from 1/1/1900 onward.

As a result when we expect Excel to treat 1:00 AM to be greater than 11:00 PM it's actually not. On Excel time scale 1:00 AM is 1/0/1900 1:00 AM and 11:00 PM is same day 11:00 PM which actually occurs 10 Hours after 1:00 AM. So when doing absolute Time Arithmetic you should set a cutoff time to separate previous or current date.

In this case 0.5 (12:00 PM) is taken as cut off for calculations.

In E5 Put the following formula

```
=IF(AND(B3>0.5,E3<=0.5),0,IF(E3>B3,E3-B3,0))
```

In E6 Put the following formula

```
=IF(AND(C3<=0.5,E4>0.5),C3+1-E4,IF(E4>=C3,0,C3-E4))
```

Now fiddle with In/Out Schedule,  actual and test it yourself if it meets your requirement.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the input. the AND function helped cutting off the loop.